# How exactly using the Looper() and Handler()

Tags: java, android, sdk

Can someone help me to correct my code.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKOvH.png)
I am trying to display realtime Count from 0 to 10 and displaying that on textView but always crash. Iam new on android but Very excited to learn.please help me explain that problem. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Looper is use to take data from content provide to UI thead where else Handler uses for send message asynchronously not bother thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm not an Android developer myself but from what i understood online, what you did is to create a Handler and provide Looperassociated with the main thread. This associate this handler to the main thread. When we post the Runnable, it gets queued in the main thread’s MessageQueue and then executed in the main thread.

Creating an own thread and providing Lopper and MessageQueue is not the right way to deal with the problem. So, Android has provided HandlerThread(subclass of Thread) to streamline the process. Internally it does the same things that we have done but in a robust way. So, always use HandlerThread.

```
private class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread { 

Handler handler;

public MyHandlerThread(String name)
 { 
super(name); 
} 
@Override 
protected void onLooperPrepared() { 
handler = new Handler(getLooper()) { 
@Override 
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
 // process incoming messages here 
// this will run in non-ui/background thread
 } 
}; 
} 
}
```

Information found at: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a

Comment: Thanks , I will get it.  so i need know more about the concepts and learn more on Thread and runnable

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create new thread under activity. there is no need to create handler.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                        final int value = i;
                        text.setText(value);
                    }
                }
            };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: can u explain how and why ?

Answer (score 0):

just :

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              ...
        }
    });
```

you can try it.